# How to retrive menu_get_object() in javascript, jQuery?

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I'd like to use the $node object in JavaScript, preferably Drupal's DOM. Is there a recommended way to do this in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this.  The most straightforward is use [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) , [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), and [drupal_json_encode](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7).

Something like this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node (&$variables)
{
  $node = $variables['node'];

  drupal_add_js(array(
    'mytheme' => array(
      'node' => $node,
    )
  ), 'setting');
}
```

The node will then be JSON encoded as `Drupal.settings.mytheme.node`.  The above is untested, but will be a decent starting point.  Keep in mind that if you have multiple nodes on a page, then this will get called multiple times.  You would need to add some logic to handle these cases.

If you do this as part of themeing, rather than a module via the [Node API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/7), then all modules that alter  the `$node` will have run at that point, so all data should be there.  Personally, I would only add the data that I need.  `$node` can get pretty big, so adding all of it would be a lot of JS on a page.

Comment: The drupal_json_encode() shouldn't be necessary, Drupal will automatically convert the whole settings array to the javascript pendant.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this will expose the complete node object to any visitor and it does very likely include confidential information like the mail address from the author of that node. It also makes the page response bigger, especially if you have large node objects with many fields. I strongly suggest you only add the properties you actually want to use in JS.

Comment: Thank you MPD for the solution above! I'm totally rolling my codes with it now!

Comment: Berdir, thanks for the append too, it's useful reminder!

Comment: Editited to reflect the comment from @Berdir.  I always forget that...